# Flume Bandwidth Throttling

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng, bandwidth-throttling

I am using 8 different services in my application and I bind each and everything with `Flume(1.6.0)`. The biggest headache is my flume instance is drinking up all my bandwidth. I need to restrict the flume sink and source to use limited amount of bandwidth. Is there any option to do so.?